# How do I enable and disable multiple game objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Need to Enable and Disable Multiple Gameobjects that contain Same Tag in Unity using C#.Thanks

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow , Please take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) to return an array of all game objects with a given tag, then use [GameObject.SetActive()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) to enable or disable them. Something like:

```
string tag = ""; // your tag
GameObject[] taggedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tag);
foreach (GameObject tagged in taggedObjects){
    tagged.Setactive(false); // or true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag() does not return inactive gameobjects. So you can leave all objects active before scene start and re close them in awake() or start().

And unity 2020 would have that feature which find inactive gameobjects too.

Comment: Can you be more specific please. With a Script or Something . Please I am a Newbie

Answer (score -1):

Above answers mess up with my camera or sort of. So, I Did my own code based on the answers.( Which is Inserted Below) (Posting It for Future Uses) Thanking Everyone who Answered.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;


public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float restarttimer = 3f;
    public GameObject Ninja;
    public GameObject Covid;
    public GameObject[] Buttons;
    public GameObject[] Ground;
    public GameObject[] HP;
    public GameObject[] panelgo;

    void Start()
    {

        //Ninja
        Debug.Log("Generating Hero");
        Ninja.SetActive(true);
        //enemy
        Debug.Log("Generating Enemy");
        Covid.SetActive(true);
        //ground
        Debug.Log("Generating Ground");
        foreach (GameObject tagged in Ground)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(true); // or true
        }
        //HP
        foreach (GameObject tagged in HP)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(true); // or true
        }
        //Buttons
        foreach (GameObject tagged in Buttons)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(true); // or true
        }
        //GameOver
        foreach (GameObject tagged in panelgo)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(false); // or true
        }

    }
    public void GameOver()
    {
        Ninja.SetActive(false);
        Covid.SetActive(false);
        foreach (GameObject tagged in Ground)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(false); // or true
        }
        foreach (GameObject tagged in HP)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(false); // or true
        }
        foreach (GameObject tagged in Buttons)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(false); // or true
        }
        foreach (GameObject tagged in panelgo)
        {
            tagged.SetActive(true); // or true
        }
    }
    public void buttonrestart()
    {
        Invoke("restart", restarttimer);
    }
    public void restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

}
```

P.S COVID Funny Name for enemy ;)
-------------------THE THREAD IS CLOSED--------------------------